# How to find the last subdirectory of a path, or the previous one if the last one name is in a list of names?

Tags: batch-file

#### TL,DR:

I'd need a batch file which,
for every folder i dropped on it, finds the top-most subdirectory whos name is not in a list of names.

#### Explanation:

I have a folder structure like this:

```
Presets
|
+--- Author 1
|    |
|    +--- A1-Library 1
|    |    |
|    |    \--- Synth
|    |
|    \--- A1-Library 2
|
+--- Author 2
|    |
|    \--- A2-Library 1
|
+--- Library 4
|
\--- Library 5
     |
     +--- Author 3
     |    |
     |    +--- Genre 1
     |    |    |
     |    |    \--- Bass
     |    |
     |    \--- Genre 2
     |
     \--- Author 4
```

Supposing that my list of directory names is `bass`, `pad`, `synth`, I need to end up with this structure:

```
Presets
|
+--- Author 1
|    |
|    +--- A1-Library 1
|    |    |
|    |    +--- Bass
|    |    |
|    |    +--- Synth
|    |    |
|    |    \--- Pad
|    |
|    +--- A1-Library 2
|         |
|         +--- Bass
|         |
|         +--- Synth
|         |
|         \--- Pad
|
+--- Author 2
|    |
|    \--- A2-Library 1
|         |
|         +--- Bass
|         |
|         +--- Synth
|         |
|         \--- Pad
|
+--- Library 4
|    |
|    +--- Bass
|    |
|    +--- Synth
|    |
|    \--- Pad
|
\--- Library 5
     |
     +--- Author 3
     |    |
     |    +--- Genre 1
     |    |    |
     |    |    +--- Bass
     |    |    |
     |    |    +--- Synth
     |    |    |
     |    |    \--- Pad
     |    |
     |    \--- Genre 2
     |         |
     |         +--- Bass
     |         |
     |         +--- Synth
     |         |
     |         \--- Pad
     |
     \--- Author 4
          |
          +--- Bass
          |
          +--- Synth
          |
          \--- Pad
```

This is what i've done for now, mostly by "aggregating" answers found in this site:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Check if any arguments were provided to the batch file
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo No folders to process.
    pause
    goto :exit
)

:: Specify the folder names to create
set "folderNames=Bass Pad Synth"

:input_loop
:: Use the first argument as the target folder
set "targetFolder=%~1"
REM ==== THIS SHOULD BE THE LAST SUBFOLDER OF "%~1"

:: Loop through each folder name and create the folders
for %%f in (%folderNames%) do (
    md "!targetFolder!\%%f"
)

echo Subfolders created in %targetFolder%
pause
:: Look for the next dropped folder
SHIFT

if "%~1"=="" (
    :: Ok, done.
    goto :exit
)
goto :input_loop

:exit
```

This batch works if i drop multiple folders, creates the folder in them, and does not show any error if the folders already exists.

But

1. it is not trying to recurse the subfolders because i've not fully understood how to do it
2. i don't know how to avoid to create the "bass" folder inside an already existing "bass" folder, but eventually create the "pad" one if it is missing.

Comment: In reformatting your directory strutures, it appears that you are not dealing with topmost, but the bottommost. You appear to have more than one question here, please deal with only one per submission.

Comment: Please don't use broken labels (`::`) for comments. They work fine at the top level, but tend to do very unexpected things in code blocks (like your `:: Ok, done`). Better use the correct command `Rem` (like **rem**ark) instead.

Comment: Your question 2.: don't avoid it. `md` won't touch the folder if it already exists. You can suppress the unavoidable "error" ("folder already exists") by just redirecting it to nirwana: `md "!targetFolder!\%%f" 2>nul` The rest of your question(s) is unclear. What do you mean with "recursive"? What do you mean with `THIS SHOULD BE THE LAST SUBFOLDER OF "%~1"`? (literal answer: `%~nx1` - see `call /?`)

Comment: @Stephan: what i mean is: if i drop the "libreary 5" folder on my current bat file, it creates the new folders in it. Instead, it should reach "Genre 1", "Genre 2" and "Author 4" and create the new folders in each of them. BUT: "Genre 1" already has the "Bass" folder, and i dont want the folders being created in there; instead the algolrithm have to stops at "Genre 1" even if there's another subfolder, 'cause the last subfolder name is contained in the list of folders to be created.

Comment: @Compo: it is just one question, splitted in two parts., English is not my native language, sorry. May my previous comment to Stephan is more clear?

Comment: get the subfolders of the dropped folder? `for /d %%s in ("!targetFolder!\*") do ...` Recursive? `for /d /r ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "newleaves=\bass \synth \pad"

:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" GOTO maketemp
(FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%e IN (*) DO ECHO %%e)>"%tempfile%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('FINDSTR /v /e /i /l "%newleaves%" "%tempfile%"'
) DO FIND "%%e\" "%tempfile%">nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  FOR %%y IN (%newleaves%) DO ECHO MD "%%e%%y"
)

DEL "%tempfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

All you'd need to do is run the job, substituting each required top-level directory for `sourcedir`.

First, make a tempfile name.
Use `for /d /r` to create a recursive directoryname list in the tempfile.
Use `findstr` to find the entries in `tempfile` that do not (/v) end (/e) with case-insensitive (/i) literal (/l) (list of "new" leaves, space-separated and each started with a backslash)
Find whether `directoryname\` exists in `tempfile` (which means it's not a leaf as it has subdirectories) and if that string does not exist, create the new leaves
Finally, kill the tempfile.

Naturaaly, this will attempt to create the new leaves anew where they already exist. In this case, `md` will report an error which can be suppressed by appending `2>nul` to the `md` command as already stated.

Comment: Well, i'm having a hard time understanding your "FOR" block, as why there's need for a temp file, but your code inserted in my `input_loop` works, so i accepted your answer. Thanks :)